# Why is Log4j2 not logging inside Spring Boot Application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2, slf4j

I'm trying to use spring boot starter and spring boot starter web. So far I've got what I think is a pretty simple set up.  I can see that the application is obviously finding and using the `log4j2-spring.xml` file so my question is why doesn't anything from the MyRunner class log via log4j2?  It does execute and the `System.out.println()` statements are writing to the console but the LOG.error messages are not.  Please help.

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>iim</name>
    <description>Demo</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**log4j2-spring.xml:**

```
<Properties>
    <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
        %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5p [%F:%L] %m%n
    </Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>
    <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
    </Console>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>

    <logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN" />      
    <logger name="org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.BaseJdbcLogger" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="java.sql" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="org.mybatis" level="ERROR" />

    <Root level="INFO">
        <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

**Application.java:**

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.demo")
public class Application {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOG.warn("********** Starting the application");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Component
    public class MyRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
        @Override
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(String.format("%s!!!", "HELLO WORLD"));
            LOG.error(String.format("%s!!!", "HELLO WORLD"));

            Stream.of("John Travolta", "Julia Childs", "Jennifer Anniston", "Helen Hunt", "Rachel Green").forEach(n -> {
                System.out.println(n);
                LOG.error(n);
            });

        }
    }
}
```

**Console Output:**

```
2019-12-11 10:08:12,294 [restartedMain] INFO  [DirectJDKLog.java:173] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2019-12-11 10:08:12,296 [restartedMain] INFO  [DirectJDKLog.java:173] Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-12-11 10:08:12,297 [restartedMain] INFO  [DirectJDKLog.java:173] Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.27]
2019-12-11 10:08:12,377 [restartedMain] INFO  [DirectJDKLog.java:173] Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-12-11 10:08:12,818 [restartedMain] INFO  [HikariDataSource.java:110] HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-12-11 10:08:12,968 [restartedMain] INFO  [HikariDataSource.java:123] HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-12-11 10:08:13,407 [restartedMain] INFO  [Slf4jLogger.java:42] SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db_example.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
2019-12-11 10:08:13,413 [restartedMain] INFO  [Slf4jLogger.java:42] SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db_example.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
2019-12-11 10:08:13,415 [restartedMain] INFO  [Slf4jLogger.java:42] SELECT `LOCKED` FROM db_example.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK WHERE ID=1
2019-12-11 10:08:13,428 [restartedMain] INFO  [Slf4jLogger.java:42] Successfully acquired change log lock
2019-12-11 10:08:13,967 [restartedMain] INFO  [Slf4jLogger.java:42] Reading resource: com/demo/db/liquibase/tables/user.sql
2019-12-11 10:08:14,014 [restartedMain] INFO  [Slf4jLogger.java:42] SELECT MD5SUM FROM db_example.DATABASECHANGELOG WHERE MD5SUM IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1
2019-12-11 10:08:14,015 [restartedMain] INFO  [Slf4jLogger.java:42] SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db_example.DATABASECHANGELOG
2019-12-11 10:08:14,016 [restartedMain] INFO  [Slf4jLogger.java:42] Reading from db_example.DATABASECHANGELOG
2019-12-11 10:08:14,016 [restartedMain] INFO  [Slf4jLogger.java:42] SELECT * FROM db_example.DATABASECHANGELOG ORDER BY DATEEXECUTED ASC, ORDEREXECUTED ASC
2019-12-11 10:08:14,025 [restartedMain] INFO  [Slf4jLogger.java:42] Successfully released change log lock
2019-12-11 10:08:14,087 [restartedMain] INFO  [DirectJDKLog.java:173] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
HELLO WORLD!!!
John Travolta
Julia Childs
Jennifer Anniston
Helen Hunt
Rachel Green
```

Comment: Just to check. Are you sure that you are importing the proper `Logger` and `LoggerFactory` classes?

Comment: I think so - I'll add the imports to Application.java in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code with few changes to work on my IDE, and it is working perfectly fine, below is the updated code, this code may help you to dig down your issue:

```
package com.example.demo;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOG.warn("********** Starting the application");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

     @Component
    public class MyRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
        @Override
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(String.format("%s!!!", "HELLO WORLD"));
            LOG.error(String.format("%s!!!", "HELLO WORLD"));

            Stream.of("John Travolta", "Julia Childs", "Jennifer Anniston", "Helen Hunt", "Rachel Green").forEach(n -> {
                System.out.println(n);
                LOG.error(n);
            });

        }
    }
}
```

I have kept below log xml(log4j2-spring.xml) under - src/main/resource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
<Properties>
    <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
        %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5p [%F:%L] %m%n
    </Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>
    <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="shree - ${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
    </Console>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>

    <logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN" />      
    <logger name="org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.BaseJdbcLogger" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="java.sql" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="org.mybatis" level="ERROR" />

    <Root level="INFO">
        <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Removed mybatis and jdbc dependencies as spring was asking for db configuration. Those Jar might be causing the issues in your code(overriding your log configurations):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

 <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

       <!--  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

       <!--  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

       <!--  <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

output:

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.1.RELEASE)

shree - 2019-12-11 22:58:03,221 [restartedMain] INFO  [StartupInfoLogger.java:55] Starting Application on LAPTOP-FS2FJ2C3 with PID 6044 (C:\Users\shrir\eclipse-workspace-jee-code\demo\target\classes started by shrir in C:\Users\shrir\eclipse-workspace-jee-code\demo)
shree - 2019-12-11 22:58:03,228 [restartedMain] INFO  [SpringApplication.java:651] No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
shree - 2019-12-11 22:58:04,014 [restartedMain] INFO  [DirectJDKLog.java:173] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
shree - 2019-12-11 22:58:04,014 [restartedMain] INFO  [DirectJDKLog.java:173] Starting service [Tomcat]
shree - 2019-12-11 22:58:04,015 [restartedMain] INFO  [DirectJDKLog.java:173] Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.27]
shree - 2019-12-11 22:58:04,074 [restartedMain] INFO  [DirectJDKLog.java:173] Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
shree - 2019-12-11 22:58:04,402 [restartedMain] INFO  [DirectJDKLog.java:173] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
shree - 2019-12-11 22:58:04,423 [restartedMain] INFO  [StartupInfoLogger.java:61] Started Application in 1.478 seconds (JVM running for 2.412)
HELLO WORLD!!!
shree - 2019-12-11 22:58:04,424 [restartedMain] ERROR [Application.java:36] HELLO WORLD!!!
John Travolta
shree - 2019-12-11 22:58:04,424 [restartedMain] ERROR [Application.java:40] John Travolta
Julia Childs
shree - 2019-12-11 22:58:04,424 [restartedMain] ERROR [Application.java:40] Julia Childs
Jennifer Anniston
shree - 2019-12-11 22:58:04,425 [restartedMain] ERROR [Application.java:40] Jennifer Anniston
Helen Hunt
shree - 2019-12-11 22:58:04,425 [restartedMain] ERROR [Application.java:40] Helen Hunt
Rachel Green
shree - 2019-12-11 22:58:04,425 [restartedMain] ERROR [Application.java:40] Rachel Green
```

This might not be your solution, but will help you to find the issue.

Adding code in Answer section as cant explain in comment section

Comment: Ok based on your testing and the fact that it worked for you, I've gone back and cut out absolutely everything extra...turned out that I had two log4j2 config files.  The one that I posted here, and the one that was being used by spring-boot.  In that log4j2 config file I had this line:
<logger name="com.demo" level="DEBUG" additivity="false" />
so I removed the additivity="false" and that seems to have fixed the problem.  Chalk one up for attention to details.  and thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct except the main method where you have to write log statement after run statement, otherwise everything is correct and it should log.
FYI boot default log level is set to INFO.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    LOG.warn("********** Starting the application");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding...I have tried your suggestion and it does not log anything.  I'm guessing the problem is in something I don't understand about Spring Boot and when the Logger is available but I'll be darned if I can find it.

Answer (score 0):

There is very less probability that you might be having any issue with log4j2.xml or log4j2-spring.xml. Most likely problem is in your pom.

I would suggest to run mvn:dependeny:tree and exclude spring-boot-starter-logging from all the dependencies in your class path.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I hope this would help. No need to explicitly give logging config file location in application.properties unless it is outside your project classpath.